# Android set click event for dynamically created lists

Tags: java, android, json, listview

One of my android learning project I am creating a list view from a dynamic json object. Its creating view perfectly. The following is my code

```
final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    String json = "[{\"name\":\"Name 1\",\"number\":\"num 1\"},{\"name\":\"Name 2\",\"number\":\"num 1\"}]";


try {
    JSONArray array = (JSONArray) new JSONTokener(json).nextValue();

    String[] stringarray = new String[array.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        stringarray[i] = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringarray); 
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
    // handle JSON parsing exceptions...
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now I am trying to add a click event for each list and also need to show an another activity and show only this list's contents. I didn't have any idea how to do this.

Can anyone please help me ?
Thanks in advance

UPDATE

```
final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        String json = "[{\"name\":\"Name 1\",\"number\":\"num 1\"},{\"name\":\"Name 2\",\"number\":\"num 1\"}]";
        try {
            JSONArray array = (JSONArray) new JSONTokener(json).nextValue();

            String[] stringarray = new String[array.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                stringarray[i] = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringarray); 
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

            adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                        long arg3) {
                    // Start a indent to start new activity and store necessary information hhere
                }

            });

            } catch (JSONException e) {
            // handle JSON parsing exceptions...
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting onItemClick Listener for the listview like this

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        String text=arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
        Intent i=new Intent(context, secondActiviy.class);
        i.putExtra("name", text);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

And in your Activity get the Extra like this

```
String name=getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
```

show this text in the textview

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply .. my code updated .. is the code right now ?

Comment: set onClick Listener for `listview` not for Adapter , i.e for your `lv`

Answer (score 2):

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // Use an indent to start new activity and store necessary information in the indent
    }

});
```

On How to start an activity using indent, [check this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Comment: onItemClick Listener is for listview not for Adapter

Comment: Yeah sorry my bad. @Pragnani is right, refer to: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html